# How to extract the value of an input element from a web page using python?

Tags: python, get

I am working on a project to extract the next three upcoming busses' e.t.a. from the bus tracker Miami website, but for some reason they display these times using an input element with an empty value in HTML. I am no expert on HTML so I am sure they must have their reason, likely some sort of async script in javascript or something. When I do a get request on this website from python I can see the input fields but next to values its empty, same when I inspect them using chrome. I can see their values but only after going into the accessibility tab in the chrome inspect utility. Is there any way to see this value using python? The website is "https://www.miamidade.gov/transportation-publicworks/bustracker.asp?RouteID=37&Dir=Northbound&StopID=7535&Sequence=42" just for reference
[here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSmxj.png) and [here is where I can see the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvkTh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the request being made by the page in your browser's debug tools network tab.

Make a request to `https://www.miamidade.gov/transportation-publicworks/mobile/xml/bustracker/?RouteID=37&Dir=Northbound&StopID=7535&Sequence=42` instead and parse the returned XML.

Comment: wow, that solved it instantly. Thank you so much. Is this normal for xml to be put into the html using input? For future reference

Comment: It's possible they're serving this data over an API to allow for mobile apps to retrieve the same data using the same endpoint.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense since they also give this information on their mobile app